# Making Dirichlet's approximation theorem constructive via continued fractions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions, diophantine-approximation

Given a real number $\alpha\in \lbrack 0,1\rbrack$ and an integer $Q>0$, Dirichlet's approximation theorem guarantees the existence of a rational $a/q$, $q\leq Q$, such that
$$\left|\alpha - \frac{a}{q}\right|\leq \frac{1}{q Q}.$$

Question: how do we find such a $q\leq Q$?

Continued fractions give answers to related but slightly different questions (finding $q$ such that $|\alpha - a/q|\leq 1/q Q$; finding best approximants). Can we use continued fractions to find a rational $a/q$ answering my question above?

(I suppose so, but I'd like to know how! Perhaps it is obvious.)

(Yes, I know, I should have learnt this in elementary school.)

Comment: Yes, there is a theorem which states that the best approximant for a given $Q$ is given by some approximant in the continued fraction expansion. See for example Hardy and Wright 3ed. for a discussion of this.

Comment: a clear short document, among others (http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/118r_spring_05/handouts/approximation.pdf)

Comment: On JeanMarie's answer: no, that does not answer the question above!

Comment: However, Them 164 in Hardy-Wright does (and so does Them 9 in Khinchin). The best-approximate property is neither needed nor immediately useful.